# What is a general outline for graphics programming on Android?

Tags: android, graphics, methods, canvas, android-activity

I'm familiar with Java but am just starting out Android programming, and don't really know what I need to make things happen. I'm trying to work with a Canvas, I'm basically making an app that reads real-time data and makes a constantly changing graph based off of it, with some buttons and other interactive UI. What are the methods I need to implement? For example, in "regular" Java, I know I would NEED to have

```
public void init(){//...}
public void paint(Graphics g) {//...}
public void run(){//...}
public static void main (String argv[]) {//...}
//...and more
```

Based on sample code that I found it seems like I need the following general outline (plus my own miscellaneous functions and classes).

```
public class MyClass extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){//initialization and setup}
    public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
        public MySurfaceView(Context context){//constructor}
        public void onResumeMySurfaceView(){//???}
        public void onPauseMySurfaceView(){//deal with user leaving the activity}
        public void run(){//...}
        public boolean onTouchEvent(){//...}
    }
}
```

Do I need all of these? What more/else do I need? And, what goes in each of the methods (e.g., where does the stuff I would normally put in paint(Graphics g) go)?

I realize this is a very general question that's kind of big, and would appreciate either tips or a link to a tutorial that is more specific than, say, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://www.amazon.com/Hello-Android-Introducing-Development-Programmers/dp/1934356565/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1309211182&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356565)

I would suggest getting a good book like the one above.

Comment: Thanks, but I only have about $8 in my bank account, and I'd hope to be able to find what I need to know somewhere online for free. I know the information's out there, just not where to find it :/